# CSS Nav not aligning under parent

Tags: css, nav

I am having a slight issue with my nav bar that I cant get fixed. The child1 level is floating to the left when I want it to float under the parent.

Here is my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/rrdsV/

The two navs that have options are "Page Styles" and "Third Party Plugins"

Thank you in advance!
George

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just apply `position: relative` to your parent - [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/rrdsV/1/)

```css
#navcontainer ul li {
    display: inline;
    padding-right: 15px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: visible; /* to satisfy 1.8% of IE7 users */
}
```